# Decrement value in a loop

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a query model where every time a query is posted, specific users are notified by mail and their records are decremented by 1.
Mail is working fine but the decrement is happening by the number of users identified and not 1.

Have tried various P&C.

```
$exclusive = DB::table('user_plans')
    ->leftJoin('companies', 'companies.id' , '=', 'user_plans.user_id')
    ->select('user_plans.*')
    ->where('user_plans.service_id' , '=', $input['project'])
    ->where('user_plans.lead_type' , '=', 2)
    ->where('user_plans.count' , '>', 0)
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();

$shared = DB::table('user_plans')
    ->leftJoin('companies', 'companies.id' , '=', 'user_plans.user_id')
    ->select('user_plans.*')
    ->where('user_plans.service_id' , '=', $input['project'])
    ->where('user_plans.lead_type' , '=', 1)
    ->where('user_plans.count' , '>', 0)
    ->limit(500)
    ->get();

$project = DB::table('services')
    ->select('services.*')
    ->where('services.id' , '=', $input['project'])
    ->get();

if (count($exclusive) > 0) {
    foreach ($exclusive as $exclusive) {
        Mail::send('emails.exclusive', array(
            'name'    => $input['name'],
            'email'   => $input['email'],
            'phone'   => $input['phone'],
            'detail'  => $input['detail'],
            'project' => $project[0]->name,
            'budget'  => $input['budget']
        ), function($message) use ($exclusive) {
            $message
                ->to($exclusive->lead_email)
                ->subject('CXO Forest Contact Us!');
        });

        //This part is not working
        $deduct =  DB::table('user_plans')
            ->where('user_plans.user_id' , '=', $exclusive->user_id)
            ->where('user_plans.count' , '>', 0)
            ->where('user_plans.type' , '=', 2)                 
            //->get();
            ->decrement('count', 1);
    }
} else {
    if (count($shared) > 0) {           
        foreach ($shared as $shared) {
            Mail::send('emails.exclusive', array(
                'name'    => $input['name'],
                'email'   => $input['email'],
                'phone'   => $input['phone'],
                'detail'  => $input['detail'],
                'project' => $project[0]->name,
                'budget'  => $input['budget']
            ), function($message) use ($shared) {
                $message
                    ->to($shared->lead_email)
                    ->subject('CXO Forest Contact Us!');
            });

            $deductx = DB::table('user_plans')
                ->where('user_plans.user_id' , '=', $shared->user_id)
                ->where('user_plans.count' , '>', 0)
                ->where('user_plans.type' , '=', 2)
                ->decrement('count', 1);
        }
    } else {
        Mail::send('emails.exclusive', array(
            'name'    => $input['name'],
            'email'   => $input['email'],
            'phone'   => $input['phone'],
            'detail'  => $input['detail'],
            'project' => $project[0]->name,
            'budget'  => $input['budget']
        ), function($message) use ($shared) {
            $message
                ->to('amit.khare@studyspectrum.com')
                ->subject('Urgent: This lead does not have any takers');
        });
    }
}
```

Every time the code runs, deduct should reduce `user_plans` by 1 and not the number of emails sent.

Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the part part that is not working, try this:

```
DB::table('user_plans') ->where('user_plans.user_id' , '=', $exclusive->user_id) ->where('user_plans.count' , '>', 0) ->where('user_plans.type' , '=', 2)  ->take(1)->delete();
```